# How can I select the output of maven dependency:list?

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-dependency

I have a big group of projects and they depend on each others with `pom.xml`.
I want to get the relationships of these dependencies among projects in a file by shell. `mvn dependency:list` is the key command, but the result is not satisfied.

> https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html

with the guide, i have use some parameters, but the result is not good enough

now the command is:

```
mvn dependency:list -DincludeGroupIds=group -DoutputFile=dependency.xml -DappendOutput=true
```

and the result in ***dependency.xml*** is:

```
group:project1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile

group:project2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile

……
```

I want to select the output of `mvn dependency:list` with the format like that:

```
project1

project2

……
```

Just no `jar`, `SNAPSHOT` or `complie` words, which are unneeded.

So, I want to konw, how can I get the result output to a file in this format?

Can I just get this result by adding the parameters with `mvn dependency:list`?

Although `sed` or `awk` is an option.

Comment: If a post-processing step is feasible for you. You might run `sed "s/\( *\)[^:]*:\([^:]*\):.*/\1\2/" dependencies.xml` (this prints to the console, only to show the principle).

Comment: post-processing step, nice word!  I have done this by sed. thx, man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

before i can repeat the guide from `maven dependency plugin`, i choose to use `sed`.

a man give me a word **"post-processing step"**, nice word.

and my solution is :

```
sed -i "s/group://g" dependency.xml
sed -i "s/:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile//g" dependency.xml
sed -i "s/^[ \t]*//g" dependency.xml
sed -i "s/[ \t]*$//g" dependency.xml
```