# How can i get the program name list of codes which changed both in two branches when i run "git merge" from dev-A to dev-B

Tags: git, github, gitlab

When I run "git merge" from dev-A tp dev-B, I input the following commands in the console.

```
git checkout dev-A
git checkout dev-B
git merge dev-A &> LOG
```

And after that, what can i get in the `LOG` is the program (file) name, like the `pom.xml`  or `Gather.java` as the following content in `LOG`, which has been changed in branch dev-A, whether it just fast forward into the dev-B or make conflicts when merging.

---

`LOG` :

```
twd-place:
Updating c6157fg..8eceqaa
Fast-forward
 pom.xml                                        | 223 +++++++++++----------
 .../auto/srf/place/PlaceAutoServiceImpl.java   |  26 ++-
 .../auto/srf/place/srf_auto_place.xml          |  23 ++-

twd-head:
Updating 082a5cd..cr2dedc
Fast-forward
 pom.xml                                        |  26 +-
 .../gather/Gather.java                         |  44 ++-

Auto-merging src/main/scripts/TWD.properties
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/main/scripts/TWD.properties
Auto-merging src/main/resources/com/twd/head/config/discovery.xml
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/main/resources/com/twd/head/config/discovery.xml
```

---

I'll use `sed` to edit the `LOG`, and the result is like that:

---

`LOG` :

```
twd-place:
pom.xml
.../auto/srf/place/PlaceAutoServiceImpl.java
.../auto/srf/place/srf_auto_place.xml

twd-head:
pom.xml
.../gather/Gather.java
src/main/scripts/TWD.properties
src/main/resources/com/twd/head/config/discovery.xml
```

---

But I want the program (file) name list without the program (file) whose codes just are changed in the dev-A only. It means I want the program list whose codes are modified both in dev-A and dev-B, including the one which make confilcts in merging and the other one not.

I draw a picture to discuribe the situation.

For example, the program (file) `.../auto/srf/place/PlaceAutoServiceImpl.java` is modifed only in dev-A, so I need to delete it. It means  `.../auto/srf/place/PlaceAutoServiceImpl.java`  is the **blue part** in the picture, which I don't need. And `src/main/scripts/TWD.properties` is modified both in dev-A and dev-B, for which conflicts ouccr. It's the **red part**.  And `.../gather/Gather.java` is also modified both in dev-A and dev-B while no error comes. it's the **green part**.

So how can I get **the green part and the red part** in the picture, or delete the **blue part**.

[image]

Comment: it's hard to say that I cannot upload the picture because I have no 10 reputations.  can u guys help me to click the other answer I have done here. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214959/how-can-i-select-the-output-of-maven-dependencylist/57228800#57228800)

Comment: You should be able to add a link to the picture even if cannot upload.

Comment: it's a way.  thanks man.  the picture is in here. https://blog.csdn.net/inkflow/article/details/105005786

Comment: When you say “program” do you mean “file”?

Comment: Yes. the file name like `Operator.java` or `consumer.xml`

Comment: any one  is familiar with git？